# Getting Bad Request 400 when getting json from URL in node.js

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I keep getting a Bad Request error from the URL I'm calling in my node.js server file. any ideas?

I've tried external working URLS too, so it's not a localhost issue.

```
var http = require('http'),  
io = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
});
server.listen(8181);

// socket.io 
var socket = io.listen(server); 

socket.on('connection', function(client){ 

function getMessages() {

    http.get({ host: 'localhost', port: 8888, path: 'json.php' },   function(response) {

        var data = "";
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {

            socket.broadcast(JSON.parse(data));
            //console.log(data);
            //socket.broadcast('{ "alrt": "YES", "message": "Something is wrong!" }');
            //socket.broadcast('hi');
        });

    });

}

setInterval(getMessages, 1000);

client.on('message', function(){})
client.on('disconnect', function(){}); 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding slash '`/`' character in the path field of your `http.get` options object:

```
...
http.get({ host: 'localhost', port: 8888, path: '/json.php' },   function(response) {
...
```

Also you are missing `res.end();` in your http server:

```
var http = require('http'),  
    io = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
    res.end();
});
server.listen(8181);
...
```